# How to use offset and limit for inserting data in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am learning Ruby on Rails and SQlite. I saw some interesting code for the seed file while I was looking at ways around to create a seed file:

```
Classroom.all.each_with_index do |classroom, i|
  classroom.students << [Student.limit(8).offset(i*2)]
end
```

I understand that it is inserting students in the classroom but don't understand what  `limit` and `offset` are doing.

I tried to search online for this and found https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset but it didn't make anything clear to me.

Any suggestion for the resources where I can find more info on this or any example that can help me to understand this?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. Your question is off-topic because you're asking us to recommend off-site resources. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". You need to do the research instead of asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html for details)

`Student` means a SQL query to get *all* the rows from the Student table.

What each of these methods like `limit` and `offset` are doing is modifying the underlying SQL query that Rails is building.

The `limit(8)` means just get 8 items.

The `offset(i*2)` means start taking them i*2 elements down the list.

If it was just an array (and not a database table) it be like saying

`student[i*2..i*2+8-1]`

**Note** I wonder if this code has a bug in it?  It would make more sense to be `offset(i*8)` .  Then this code would take groups of 8 students and put them in different classes.

As it is this will take the first 8 students, put them in the first classroom, then take students 3-10 and putting them in the next class, etc, so some students will end up in up to 4 different classes!

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. It really makes sense now.